# Google Drive API QuickStart UnicodeDecodeError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I tried to follow the introduction of Google drive api tutorial:  developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python, but it was stuck when the example file quickstart.py running below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools


SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

def main():
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I got error as below:

```
C:\Users\mhlai.TARI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access token.json: No such file or directory
warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart.py", line 32, in main
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
  File "C:\Users\mhlai.TARI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mhlai.TARI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\tools.py", line 203, in run_flow
    ClientRedirectHandler)
  File "C:\Users\mhlai.TARI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 449, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\mhlai.TARI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\mhlai.TARI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)


UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Question 1 :I can't find token.json in introduction, and I didn't know whether it's necessary or not.

Question 2 :What could I do for the Error information?

Any answer is helpful, thanks a lot.

My develop enviroment is in python3.7

Comment: store = file.Storage('token.json')  <-- find out where that is storing stuff and make sure that your script has access

Comment: can you share the link to your tutorial? That might help. Most probably there should be instructions to generate a token

Comment: @TinaIris its probably this one https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for support information, that's my tutorial web.
I will try to find the storing stuff->it's that mean I loss one  file?

Comment: @黃瀚輝 the file in question is used to store the credentials returned by the user logging in.   Your script will need permission to write to that.

Comment: @TinaIris that question has nothing to do with the current question please dont try to confuse the issue.  This is a google drive question about python comments should stick to that not unrelated issues.